# restrict acces to "my account" only from a certain page in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oop, laravel-5

Im working on an application in Laravel and I have to create some restriction only when Im in "subusers" page... that means:

-if Im in subusers page and click the button "go to my account" I have to display a securityCheck (which I have and it is working) a form with a "write username and password"

-Otherwise account page is accesible from other pages.

That should do the job... sounds preety easy right...? well... I have no idea how to do it. Instead I created a granted acces for some minutes (15)

```
public function getAccounts()
{
    $loginTime =  new Carbon(Session::get('LoginTime'));
    $diff = $loginTime->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now());
    //after 15 minutes a password security check will be ask.

    if($diff > 15)
    {
         return redirect('SecurityCheck');
    }



    if(Auth::check() && $this->user->subscribed()){

           $data = array(
        'user'  =>$this->user,
        'users'   => $this->user->users(),
        'invoices' => $this->user->invoices()
        );
        //if(session('auth') ==1)
        //{
        return view('pages.payment.account')->with('data', $data);
        //}else{
        //$messages =array(
        //'1'  =>''
        //);
        //return view('Auth.SecurityCheck')->with('messages', $messages);
        //}
    }else{
        return view('pages.payment.join')->with('user', $this->user);
    }
}
```

this is not working as I want... cause it creates a hole in the securityCheck and I can still access to my account from "subuserspage" before the 15 minutes are over... then it gonna ask securityCheck everytime I click on "my account" (which I dont want... I just want the securityCheck step on the subusers page)

How do I create a restriction to "my account" only from subusers page?

Comment: if you dont know how to help, don click just minus.... simply leave the page. thanks. the problem is solved and no thanks to you tht click on minus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getAccounts()
{  

    if(Auth::check() && ($this->user->subscribed() || $this->user->subscribed())){

           $data = array(
        'user'  =>$this->user,
        'users'   => $this->user->users(),
        'invoices' => $this->user->invoices()
        );

        return view('pages.payment.account')->with('data', $data);

    }else{
        return view('pages.payment.join')->with('user', $this->user);
    }
}
```

The function  should see like this and it is solved. Thanks to asll that clicked on minus just to bother.